# NoMethodError: undefined method `result' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rspec, poltergeist

I am having the following error randomly when running rspec with capybara and poltergeist:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `result' for #<NoMethodError: undefined method `fields' for nil:NilClass>
```

I think the cause may be relationed with the database connection. So, anyone can confirm it to me? I'll try to use truncation with database_cleaner, but it is SOOOO SLOW to run the entire suite with truncation!

Strategies on avoiding this and keep the specs running fast are appreciated!

The backtrace:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1147:in `translate_exception'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:284:in `rescue in log'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1256:in `select'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:in `select_all'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `block in select_all'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:75:in `cache_sql'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:61:in `select_all'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:38:in `block in find_by_sql'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:37:in `find_by_sql'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:171:in `exec_queries'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:380:in `find_first'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/orm_adapter-0.4.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:17:in `get'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:192:in `serialize_from_session'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:29:in `deserialize'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:35:in `fetch'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/proxy.rb:212:in `user'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/proxy.rb:318:in `_perform_authentication'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/proxy.rb:104:in `authenticate'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-2.2.3/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:56:in `current_admin_user'
./app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb:5:in `user_for_paper_trail'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/paper_trail-2.7.1/lib/paper_trail/controller.rb:59:in `set_paper_trail_whodunnit'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__385666484__process_action__495591669__callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/request_store-1.0.5/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/sass-3.2.5/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__267372543__call__960205176__callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'# /home/rafaelsouza/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1147:in `translate_exception'
```

Comment: The error is that you are calling the method fields in a nil class. What do you expect us to tell you about your mistake with only this line?

Comment: I think it is not inside my code. Edited the question with the backtrace.

Comment: I have a clue. I am using rspec 'before' and 'let!'. Does 'before(:each)' hooks run in a separate thread of an poltergeist js: true rspec example?

Comment: You can't run selenium/poltergeist tests using a transaction strategy- it needs to be truncation. See [this post](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) for information on including a switch that could save you some time on the tests that don't require js.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with persisted connections. https://gist.github.com/compwron/48eed93cb9e0a86affb0

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in AR 3.2.13. The explanation of the error is that there is a general exception handler inside AR that catches all exceptions and tries to translate them to meaningful and uniform errors. Here is the function source:

```
    def translate_exception(exception, message)
      case exception.result.error_field(PGresult::PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE)
      when UNIQUE_VIOLATION
        RecordNotUnique.new(message, exception)
      when FOREIGN_KEY_VIOLATION
        InvalidForeignKey.new(message, exception)
      else
        super
      end
    end
```

Everything should go well if it is *really* a database error, but if it is another error (Execution timeout if using DelayedJobs, SIGTERM, ...), then the exception handler itself will throw another exception, and this is what you see in the exception message.

This is a known bug in AR 3.2.13 and it is fixed in 3.2.14.

Look at these:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10917

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9493